# Los favicones de los sites.google

Tags: google-sites

Los favicones de los sitios de Google, no se ven en el navegador, en su lugar sale un icono de la Tierra como este: https://ibb.co/Hrv9THt

¿Le pasa a alguien más?

Gracias por responder.

---

Pongo el sitio web: https://sites.google.com/site/codigodedescuento

---

El icono que hay a la izquierda en el navegador no es el mío: https://ibb.co/3sfzwPT (es un planeta Tierra en color azul)

---

Mi icono es este: https://ibb.co/0fw1BQF

---

El problema es que quiero que figure mi icono, no otro.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Justamente.. cual es el problema???

Comment: Pon link de la web para verla.

Comment: Ya lo he editado con todas las aclaraciones que pedís.